# How to print to console or get the key of a firestore document field in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to print the underlined value `(med 1)` to the console. How can I do that? I am using a `streamBuilder` to display the data and I want to display the `key` as a `text` widget.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('/your_collection_name').snapshots()
  builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                Map<String, dynamic> data =
                    document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                print(data['med 1'];
              })
}
)
```

If you have multiple documents under the collection with med 1 field, you can access the data using this code.

Hope it helps

Comment: Happy to help @VihangaRandunu ! And btw as it's `.snapshot()`, you will recieve real-time updates. i.e even if your flutter app is running on emulator/real device and you update data on firebase console, you'll see the updates on app without the need to restart.